# how to replace value with constant value in json jolt?

Tags: json, jolt

input:

```
{
  "locationId": 100212,
  "weatherDateGmt": 1642590000,
  "geoLocation": {
    "latitude": 43.80306,
    "longitude": 143.89083
  },
  "humidity": 77,
  "currentCondition": "Mostly Clear",
  "latitude": 43.80306,
  "longitude": 143.89083
}
```

wanted output:

```
  "locationId": 100212,
  "weatherDateGmt": 1642590000,
  "humidity": 77,
  "currentCondition": "Snow",
  "latitude": 43.80306,
  "longitude": 143.89083
```

I want the `"currentCondition"` to be always `"Snow"` and without `geoLocation`

here is my jolt:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "geoLocation": null,
      "*": "&",
      "currentCondition": {
        "*": { "Snow": "currentCondition" }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

here is my output:

```
{
  "locationId" : 100212,
  "weatherDateGmt" : 1642590000,
  "humidity" : 77,
  "latitude" : 43.80306,
  "longitude" : 143.89083
}
```

the `currentCondition` has been deleted, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove those attributes(`"geoLocation"` and `"currentCondition"`) by a **remove** transformation, then use `#` notation along with a **shift** transformation such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "geoLocation": "",
      "currentCondition": ""
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "#Snow": "currentCondition"
    }
  }
]
```

[image]